# Verdaccio: cannot open config file C:\redacted\config.yaml: false

Tags: verdaccio

I am trying to install Verdaccio as windows service, following [official guide](https://verdaccio.org/docs/windows/). Before using nssm I manually tried service's command in powershell:

```
node .\node_modules\verdaccio\build\lib\cli.js -c .\config.yaml
```

However I get error:

```
cannot open config file C:\redacted\config.yaml: false
```

Where `C:\redacted\config.yaml` is correctly resolved absolute path of `.\config.yaml`.

Error doesn't happen on development Windows 10 machine, only on server with Windows server 2016. `.\config.yaml` exists and has permissions set to everything for `Everyone`. Running same command in administrator powershell works.

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered this problem before. It's actually caused by errors in the config.yaml file. However, after verdaccio v5.x, there is no longer a prompt, instead it only displays "cannot open config file /verdaccio/conf/config.yaml: false". But when I use verdaccio v4, it can prompt normally, and I don't understand why the error prompt was removed in the new version.

You can verify using Docker:

docker pull verdaccio/verdaccio:4

docker run -it --name verdaccio -p 4873:4873 -v /root/verdaccio/conf:/verdaccio/conf -v /root/verdaccio/storage:/verdaccio/storage -v /root/verdaccio/plugins:/verdaccio/plugins verdaccio/verdaccio:4

Then you can receive a prompt similar to this:

fatal--- cannot open config file /verdaccio/conf/config.yaml: YAMLException: can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key at line 170, column 5: web: zh-CN ^

You can try it out, and best regards to you.

Comment: I don't think this was the issue - exactly same config with same version of verdaccio worked on dev machine, but not on server. In the end clean reinstall of node, npm & verdaccio somehow fixed it. Still, thanks thats good advice for most cases.

Comment: Yes, this problem can be quite a headache at times, so using Docker can mitigate most issues caused by different environments.